# I can not understand how i use routing in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

What is  routing in Codeigniter? I do not understand it.

```
class teacher extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('teacher_model');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not mandatory to use route mapping. You can reach wanted page over `http://www.example.tld/controller_name/method_name/arg1/arg2`. Main purpose of route.php file is **to have set default controller**. You can read [docs about routing](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html) in CodeIgniter, but also check all [commented text](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/routes.php) in `APPPATH . 'config/routes.php'` file.

Answer (score 0):

## I think this will help you better to understand routing in Codeigniter .

Routing rules are defined in your application/config/routes.php file.

```
Few Example :
1.Here are a few routing examples:
$route['journals'] = "blogs";
2.A URL containing the word "journals" in the first segment will be remapped to the "blogs" class.
$route['blog/joe'] = "blogs/users/34";
For more Detail click Check Office Codeigniter User-guide (ellislab.com).
link:-https://ellislab.com/
```

Comment: why you need to use routing

Comment: Routing is mainly use to control where the URI segments are pointing to, in terms of controllers, actions, and parameters & for also used for modify the URL of the websites for security purposes.

Comment: ex:-  $route['blog/joe'] = "blogs/users/34"; //This show the change